# git submodule doesn't work on React project

Tags: git, github, gitlab, fetch, git-submodules

I'm working on a React project. The repo name is "namo-design-system" inside this repo I used another repo "design-system". 
 I used `git submodule` command to add "design-system" to inside src folder of "namo-design-system" 
My ide is vscode in explorer section inside src "design-system" is labeled with capital S as
submodule there is **.gitmodules** file and in it, there are the path and URL of the submodule
BUT when I use `git submodule status` nothing happens I tried it on **git version 2.37.3.windows.1** and on the integrated terminal in vscode but nothing happens
[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Looks like the submodule has been added correctly given there's files in `src/design-system`

Comment: _"there is .gitsubmodules file"_... shouldn't that be `.gitmodules`?

Comment: I want to fetch all branches in design-system from repo to my local machine

Comment: That's not how submodules work. They include another repo in your project at a specific commit

Comment: there is 4 other branches after main in design-system repo how can I access them on my machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule)

Comment: just go into the submodule directory and you can change the branch as any git repo

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you actually do have a submodule (meaning if your parent repository has a `.gitmodules` file)

A [`git submodule status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-status--cached--recursive--ltpathgt82308203) done from inside a (presumed) submodule folder should display:

```
-<sha1> ./
```

With `<sha1>` the submodule root tree SHA.